# How to make a code execute continuously every 15 minutes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, forever

Hey guys I am running a web server on node + express and for some reason my code isn't executing every 10 minutes even though I clearly have the setInterval function set there. This is just one of the 4 codes I have set in my script file (called serverScripts.js) right next to app.js and I ran it with both node serverScripts.js and used forever module on it but it still doesn't work

```
var APOD = (function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        async.waterfall([
            function Request(callback) {
                let apodUrl = 'https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=';
                let api_key = '*censored*';
                request(apodUrl+api_key, function(err, apodData) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    apodData = JSON.parse(apodData.body);
                    callback(null, apodData);
                });
            },
            function GetTableItems(apodData, callback) {
                let apodParams = { TableName: "APOD" }
                db.scan(apodParams, (err,apodTable) => {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    callback(null, apodData, apodTable);
                });
            },
            function CheckUniques(apodData, apodTable, callback) {
                let tempArr = [];
                for (let i = 0; i < apodTable.Items.length; i++) {
                    tempArr.push(apodTable.Items[i].title);
                }
                let IsItThere = _.includes(tempArr, apodData.title);
                if (!IsItThere) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        let putParams = {
                            TableName: 'APOD',
                            Item: {
                                "title": apodData.title,
                                "date": apodData.date,
                                "description": apodData.explanation,
                                "hdurl": apodData.hdurl,
                                "media_type": apodData.media_type,
                                "url": apodData.url,
                                "copyright": apodData.copyright
                            }
                        }
                        db.put(putParams, (err) => {
                            if (err) throw err;
                            console.log(`\nAdded APOD item: ---"${apodData.title}"--- to the database.\n`);
                        });
                    },1000);
                }
                else { console.log("No new APOD items."); }
                callback(null);
            }
            ]);
        APOD;
    },600000);
}());
```

Comment: the issue may not be with `setInterval` but can be because of some othe failures in your code. Please check the console

Comment: You can set some CRON job for fulfill your purpose if you want.
you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron

Comment: What does "still doesn't work" mean?   That's an insufficient description of your problem and what troubleshooting steps you've already taken and what you've learned in those steps.  A `setInterval()` doesn't just stop on its own.  There has to be some sort of observable or testable error in your code.  Do you set breakpoints in each step of your code?  Did you put `console.log()` statements throughout your code to track its progress and see where things go haywire.  Elemental debugging steps are required here.

Answer (score 1):

i think according to your question cron is the best match , you can set cron after every 15 minutes . 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron .

```
var cron = require('node-cron');

cron.schedule('0 0/15 * 1/1 * ? *', function(){
  console.log('running a task every 15 minutes');
});
```

Comment: What does node-cron offer the OP that a `setInterval()` in their already running node.js process can't do just fine?

Comment: it is a nodejs package , which we can use easily , so that you can call api after 15 min according to your requirement . cron is specially used for this , so that we can handle our API easily